# Deployment Pools - Access Denied - username needs Manage permissions to perform the action

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm attempting under "Organization Settings" to either create or rename a Deployment Pool, but get the message...

Access denied. USERNAME needs the Manage permissions to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server administrator.

I've tried to find a "Manage" permission, but can't find it anywhere. Message is very vague.

Any help greatly received - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are one of PCA member, if you don’t [have permission or correct role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops) of deployment pool, you will also could not manage the deployment pools. [image]

Contact your org owner or anyone who is administrator of deployment pool. Ask them add you and assign suitable role to you(for roles you can refer previous pic)

Assigned steps:  Organization setting—>Deployment pools —>Security—>Add, and then input your account and select the role.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked - as I thought there was no displayable "permission" called Manage, just a Role with a description on a website that says it has "Manage" - A solid Microsoft effort.